# Could not retrieve the WSDL file error using Rational Application Developer

Tags: web-services, wsdl, rad

I'm trying to generate some web service with the open source WSDL file hosted on 52north:

https://svn.52north.org/svn/swe/main/SOS/GeorefImageSOS/trunk/52nSOS-T/src/org/n52/sos_t/SOS.wsdl

I created a Dynamic Web Project and import the WSDL file. When I use web service tool to generate a client, "Operation timed out - Could not retrieve the WSDL file" error occurred. I suspect it's the import that takes too long to load all the schema.

Could any one try to generate a web service from above WSDL file? Or maybe provide suggestion on how to set up the parameters?

Thank you so much,
William

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the WSDL to your local machine, and then use the WSDL2Java command to generate your Stub.